# Compare string to regex in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I was doing

```
expect(@link.url_address == 'abc').to be_true
```

but url_address might have other text after `abc` so I am trying

```
expect(@link.url_address =~ 'abc').to be_true
```

but I am getting

```
Failure/Error: expect(@link.url_address =~ /abc/).to be_true
   expected  to respond to `true?`
```

I also tried

```
expect(@link.url_address).to =~ /abc/
```

but I get

```
 Failure/Error: expect(@link.url_address).to =~ /abc/
 ArgumentError:
   The expect syntax does not support operator matchers, so you must pass a matcher to `#to`.
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try this:

```
expect(@link.url_address).to match(/abc/)
```

Source: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations#regular-expressions